# How to make DIV scroll whole sections by mousewheel

Tags: jquery, html, css, mousewheel, scrollto

I have a ScrollTo jquery. 
I have three Sections with DIV's set to fullscreen. **ONE, TWO, THREE**
and a navigation menu directing to those respective sections. 
The ScrollTo is working perfectly, however, i want to achieve the addition of scrolling the whole sections using minimal scripts by the mousewheel to the NEXT section directly when i scroll by the wheel. 
How can I achieve this. 
I have tried using the ***fullpage.js*** but that script is exactly not what i am looking for.

*I am using only one simple jquery for the ScrollTo*

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function () {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
                if (target.length) {
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    })
```

[**JSFIDDLE HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/70n7jfy8/)

Comment: `but that script is exactly not what i am looking for`. Why not?

Comment: Because it calls all the sections through a common ID and not separate Id's @MoshFeu

Comment: @Lemdor are you talking about the anchor links for each section? What do you mean by " it calls all the sections through a common ID"?

Comment: i am looking for an alternative to that script with a custom function mentioned above. fullpage.js script i am sure could be customized but since i am not well versed in javascript editing..hence, the function on that script somehow doesnt work well with what i am trying to achieve. i hope that answers your question @Alvaro